# Cross domain login

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl

Let's say I've one site ***LoginSite*** and other two sites ***site1*** and ***site2***.

Now, If user logs in from ***LoginSite*** then he/she should be automatically logged in into the ***site1*** and ***site2***.

---

I've tried below two ways for the same

> Way1 :: using ***ajax***

I've white listed ***LoginSite's*** domain into ***site1*** and ***site2***.

But, It has only enabled cross domain ajax requests. It is not storing session for ***site1*** and ***site2***.

> Way2 :: using ***cURL***

I've tried the same using cURL by set of below code.

```
$username="mylogin@gmail.com"; 
$password="mypassword"; 
$url="http://site1.com/api/login"; 
$cookie="cookie.txt"; 

$postdata = "username=myusername@gmail.com&password=mypassword";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6"); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url); 

curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 

echo $result;  
curl_close($ch);
```

Above code is not working. There must be something missing. I guess somehow I've to return sessionID from ***site1*** and use it.

Pl. help/guide me how to do this.

***Note :*** I do not want to post form to ***site1*** or **site2**

Comment: "Above code is not working. There must be something missing. I guess somehow I've to return sessionID from site1 and use it." — That's impossible, `site2` cannot tell the browser to set a cookie for `site1`. That would be a serious security problem.

Comment: okay... so do you have any other alternative or suggestion for this? Thanks for clearing my mind I was also in doubt about this cross domain cookie thing.

Comment: If I'd had the time to fill in the gaps in my knowledge and write an answer, I would have done.

Comment: Haha... np I'm trying... I will post it if something works. btw, thanks clearing one way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**LoginSite** must generate a **UniqueID** and give it back to the connected **User**, it will be used as a **token**
When **User** connect to **site2** it will send his token, and **site2** will ask for his validity, if it still valid, so it will accept the connection and creting a session

Conclusion : think about token, validity and security :)

Comment: Yes, I'm currently trying this alternative. But somewhere I read it's possible to achieve required functionality using cURL and AJAX. 

I'm trying to send user name and password in AESencrypted format in url and I will open that in new tab.

Pl. provide your suggestion if you think it's vulnerable. BTW thanks a lot. I will accept answer if it works well.